# Call and pass parameter to Network URL(MVC) from AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to open my other second project(URL) into new Tab with passing parameter from ajax method of my first project.
I don't want to show parameter value to users.
if i do it from post url then value is passed, but it won't load view of other project.
if i use window.open then how to pass parameters, POST will not work in any ways,
as i don't get callback to ajax from second project.

I have tried all stuffs, please guide.

Comment: I suggest that you use cookies, these are always available even in through the other project and hidden enough to users.

Comment: I have done similar thing in my application too. Are both the projects under same domain?

Comment: No, not necessary. It is working with cookies. i delete it after getting values in second project. Thanks Ovis. Its really good idea.

Comment: Hi, Ovis sorry to say, but in case when cookie is disabled in browser it is not working. any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per told by Ovis, cookie is working.It is available in other project, i have deleted it once i get it.